# How to pass a variable to a WMI query run in a batch file?

Tags: command-line, arguments, wmic

I want to run the following in a batch file and prompt the user to enter "NewUserID", then insert it as a variable. Can this be done with WMI?

```
wmic useraccount where name='user'call rename name='NewUserID'
```

Answer (score 0):

why not prompt the user with `set /p` 
I did this with some HP machines to read the AssetTag field fom the BIOS.

You should be able to replace `newuserid` with your variable.

**Test**

Start a bat or cmd file.

```
@echo off
set /p _MYVARIABLE=
echo %_MYVARIABLE%
pause
```

I found a reference to wmic and they discuss variables with this command.
[Link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmic.php)

Comment: I tried it and got the following error msg:  Code:=0x80041017 Description=Invalide query, Facility=WMI